# Search Facebook events by location and proximity

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a  Facebook  API  to get events filtered by location and date, but  seems that do not exist, instead, I found this https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location-core that seems do the stuff. The problem is that I'm a newbie and I can't make it working on a php file.
Can anyone give me a hint or a direction to how implement it on a php file and how retrieve the data?
An answer for dummies will be apreciated.
Thank's

Comment: Please at least provide some referential code on which we could build on and guide on improving it.

Comment: Thank's, don't have any code yet, the idea is to retrieve the events and import them in my events manager, I know how to import the data but I miss something on how to retrieve the data from this javascipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has already translated some of that codebase to php. Take a look at PedroGabriel's  [repository](https://github.com/PedroGabriel/facebook-events-by-location) on github. I tested it by passing the parameters through a simple form (and it worked, like tobilg's  [original codebase](https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location)  at least at first glance - I haven't tested it thoroughly)

sample form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    latitude :  <input type="text"  name="lat" value="42.844018">  
    longitude: <input type="text"  name="lng" value="-106.317175">  
    distance: <input type="text"  name="distance" value="50"> 
    access_token: <input type="text"  name="access_token" value="EAACEdEos...etc">  
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You can read more about the parameters in PedroGabriel's `README.md` in his repository and do a search on `google` for `facebook access tokens`(sorry can't post more links)